# Methods to look for when checking if a javascript program is making network requests

Tags: web-browser, javascript, web

I'm trying to quickly audit a js browser extension to see if it doesn't talk to the outside. Am I right in thinking that I can just `grep` the code for the following:

- XMLHttpRequest
- fetch
- $.ajax
- axios.get
- WebSocket

I'm assuming un-obfuscated code.

Comment: @schroeder No, I hand't considered it. A cursory look at the codebase doesn't show any obfuscated though, but I guess that would be expected. I'm not familiar with how obfuscation works, but wouldn't there have to be somewhere on the code a redeclaration/assignment of the old function to its obfuscated counterpart?

Comment: it depends on what method is used, but from what you've said, obfuscated code is out of scope of the question.

Comment: @Scb: It is also possible to cause requests by adding a variety of elements (img, script, style, ...) to the DOM of the original page, by adding css with url parameters ...